# Google does not show the correct URL

Tags: url, seo

Hi I have my own URL http://www.manelsoft.com When Search by google it does not show the correct URL and google shows another URL as http://mail.dreamfordarfur.org/ but when click on this link it shows the correct address.
I added this URL to google webmaster tool few months ago and few days ago it shows an error message saying google can't accedd robots.txt on your site. Then I fixed it and added the robots.txt file. But the problem is still exists. Please anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: what search query are you typing?

Comment: On the About US page, make sure you put the "H" in Home Page so it doesn't look like ome Page.  Adding a favicon wouldn't hurt either. I agree with Stephen ... it's some spam weight-loss-drug site, just like a poker gambling site or porn site.  He just ran a whois on your site, but the canonical link rel above your closing </head> tag should work.

Answer (score 2):

You say that when you click on `http://mail.dreamfordarfur.org/` you see the "correct" address.  However, I still see mail.dreamfordarfur.org in the address bar of my browser.   To me, your full site appears to be shown.

dreamfordorful.org and manelsoft.com appear to hosted on the same server:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.dreamfordarfur.org. 14215  IN  CNAME   dreamfordarfur.org.
dreamfordarfur.org. 14215   IN  A   173.237.136.37
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.manelsoft.com.  14186   IN  CNAME   manelsoft.com.
manelsoft.com.      14186   IN  A   173.237.136.37
```

dreamfordarfur.org is registered using private DNS registration, so I can't tell who owns it.  It appears to be a spam site pushing weight loss drugs, so you don't want to be associated with it.

The problem is that the webserver you are using is misconfigured.   Your site is either set to the default site that shows up for any unrecognized host name, or the virtual host for mail.dreamfordarfur.org is pointing to the directory that hosts your manelsoft.com site.
If you have control over your web server, you should correct its configuration.

If you don't have control over this web server and are just using a brain dead hosting company, there are still some things you could do besides asking them to fix the web server.

You should put a [canonical tag](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) in each of your pages that shows what the correct url of that page should be.  For example, your home page should have the following in the `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.manelsoft.com/"/>
```

Another thing you could do is change some of your navigation to absolute links.  If you change the code for your menu to this:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a class="active" href="http://www.manelsoft.com/">Home Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.manelsoft.com/web.php">Web Development</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.manelsoft.com/desktop.php">Desktop Apps</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.manelsoft.com/about.php">About Us</a></li>
  <li class="last-item"><a href="http://www.manelsoft.com/contacts.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

It will direct web crawlers back to your real site every time they follow one of the main links on your page, even if they find your website at an incorrect url.

Answer (score -1):

I would change your robots file to read

User-Agent: *

Allow: /

This will allow Google in the next time it visits your site. This may take a few days to happen though.

Comment: That is not the correct syntax for robots.txt.  There is no "Allow" directive. The current robots.txt file he has does not appear to disallow crawling, so your "solution" will not help.

Comment: There is an allow directive: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

Comment: Google does support "Allow", but it is their extension to robots.txt.  The robots.txt standard **only** supports Disallow: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html   You want your robots.txt file to be understood by all crawlers, not just Googlebot.  You should only use Googlebot specific syntax in a specific section of the file meant for googlebot.

Comment: Kinda like this: Sitemap: http://www.domain.org/sitemap.xml.gz or Sitemap: http://www.domain.org/sitemap.xml